# D3 append element to end of text

Tags: d3.js

I have created a simple KPI box using d3.  Currently the icon and %value are static but I want them attached to the end of large KPI number so that it prevents the elements from overlapping.

eg
No issues with a small number

[image]

However, with a large number the overlap happens

[image]

How can I append the icon and %value to the end if the KPI value?

script:

```
var tile = svg.append("g").attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

//add rect
tile.append("rect")
  .attr('class', 'rect')
  .attr("rx",5 )
  .attr("ry", 5) 
  .attr("x",0 )
  .attr("y", -35)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)


//add Large KPI Number
tile.append("text")
  .data(data)
  .attr('class', 'labelx')
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", width / 2.5)
  .attr("y", 150)
  .text(function(d) {
  return formatComma(d.Value)
})



//add % variance
tile.append("text")
  .data(data)
  .attr('class', 'var')
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", width / 1.4)
  .attr("y", 130)
  .text( function(d) {
  return  formatPC(d.Var) })

//add icon
tile.selectAll(".image")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", width / 1.5)
  .attr('class', 'icon glowed')
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    if (d.Var < 0 ) {
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Red_Arrow_Down.svg/2048px-Red_Arrow_Down.svg.png"
    } else {
      return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Green_Arrow_Up.svg/1200px-Green_Arrow_Up.svg.png"
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getBBox` to determine the width of each text block after plotting, but the simpler solution would be changing the anchoring:

```
tile.append("text")
  .data(data)
  .attr('class', 'labelx')
  .attr("text-anchor", "end") // position the end of the text here
  .attr("x", width / 2.5)
  .attr("y", 150)
  .text(function(d) {
  return formatComma(d.Value)
})
   
//add % variance
tile.append("text")
  .data(data)
  .attr('class', 'var')
  .attr("text-anchor", "start") // position the start of the var at the same spot
  .attr("x", width / 2.5)
  .attr("y", 130)
  .text( function(d) {
  return  formatPC(d.Var) })
```